# Are these phrases synonymous?

Tags: idioms

> She kept her **pinned to the ground** = She kept her **pinned down**.
>
> She **came to the bottom** = She **came down**.
>
> **Read it out.** = **Read it to them.**
>
> She is **off-duty** = She is **out of duty**.

Comment: To the close voter (I see only one close-vote, at the moment), this is not a proofreading question. The OP just wants to check whether his understanding as shown in the paraphrases is correct or not. -- To @AnubhavSingh, I think the last one would be fine if you changed *She is out of duty* to *She is not on duty*.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ah, I see! If that's the case, we have another close-reason for it: *This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context. See: Details, Please.*

Comment: This is four questions, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would say yes, they are synonymous
2. Not necessarily. She could come down without going all the way to the bottom. Say she was standing on level 5 and walked to level 3. Then she came down, but she did not come to the bottom.

   3. Not necessarily. "Read it out" just means reading aloud, which technically someone could do in an empty room. "Read it to them" explicitly states who she is reading to.
   4. "Out of duty" is not good English. I'm not even sure what that would mean.

Answer (score 2):

1. The two sentences "She kept her pinned to the ground" and "She kept her pinned down" can have dissimilar meanings. The idiom **pinned down** can refer, for instance, to a military unit which is prevented from moving by heavy fire. We would say that such a unit is "Pinned down," but we would almost never say that such a unit is "Pinned to the ground." "Pinned to the ground" is likely to be heard in the context of wrestling or hand-to-hand combat. The phrases would seldom be used interchangeably, although they do describe similar actions. They are not synonymous.
2. One can "come down" without "going to the bottom." The subject might choose to come only halfway down! The phrases are not synonymous.
3. "Read it out" would probably be understood as "Read it aloud," which is to say "Read it in an audible voice and not to one's self." However, one may or may not have an audience! "Read it to *them,*" on the other hand, requires that the subject read *it* to an audience of *them*. The phrases are not synonymous.
4. "She is off-duty" means "She has finished with her responsibilities for now," with some implication that her responsibilities will continue at a later time. "She is out of duty" has no idiomatic or other obvious meaning in English. The phrases are not synonymous.

Comment: I see what you mean about "pinned down," but to explain why I said I thought they were synonymous, I was going by the "default" meaning of pinned down. You are right that pinned down could mean something different in a military context or other contexts, but if you just say, "She has her pinned down" without any other context or explanation, I think it at least strongly implies that you are talking about "pinned to the ground."